# Specific object creation date and time

Tags: swift, sorting

I am creating objects in a `for` loop and need a specific creation date and time so that I can tell what order they were created in. I also need to save this `dateTime` as a `String` and still be able to get the creation order from it.
Is this possible?

I understand how to get a date and time when the object is created but it is not specific enough when converted to a string.

Currently i just have a small extension for Date:

```
extension Date {
    func currentDateTimeAsString() -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy"

        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

But this obviously isn't accurate enough, and I don't think adding milliseconds to the time is going to help much either?

I understand there are ways around this by adding counts etc to the objects so that i can use that to get the order, but i know if i use Date before converting it to a string it will order it correctly, so there is some information hiding in there that i need to convert to the string as well.

Comment: Add some code to show what you are doing now.

Comment: Have added my current code but im not sure its much use :)

Comment: If you want to have unique times for object creation, you probably need to get down to nanoseconds. Even then, you can't be guaranteed that they will be unique. Perhaps add a counter as well as the time. Sort based on the counter alone. Display based on the time you're collecting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your object as:

```
struct SomeData: CustomStringConvertible {
    let dateTimeStr: String
    private static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        return formatter
    }
    init() {
        let creationDate = Date()
        dateTimeStr = SomeData.dateFormatter.string(from: creationDate)
    }
    var creationDate: Date {
        return SomeData.dateFormatter.date(from: dateTimeStr)!
    }
    var description: String {//just to print
        return dateTimeStr
    }
}
```

Then create it in for loop as:

```
var objArr = [SomeData]()
for _ in 0...5 {
   objArr.append(SomeData())
}
print("\(objArr)")
```

> Output: [18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.684, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.690, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.692, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.696, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.699, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.704]

As you can see, they are already sorted according to creation time.

But still you want to sort it again, do it like:

```
let sortedObjArr = objArr.sorted(by: { $0.creationDate < $1.creationDate })
print("\(sortedObjArr)")
```

> Output: [18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.684, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.690, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.692, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.696, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.699, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.704]

If you want reverse order, do this:

```
let sortedObjArr = objArr.sorted(by: { $0.creationDate > $1.creationDate })
print("\(sortedObjArr)")
```

> Output: [18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.704, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.699, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.696, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.692, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.690, 18-Oct-2017 12:50:09.684]

Comment: Is this the most detail you can get out of Date?

Comment: What details you want to get out of date?

Comment: As in more specific time or is milliseconds the smallest?

Comment: I think milliseconds is the smallest allowed!